# Return value size or type of a system call in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls

I understand, from looking at kernel code, the linux system call return type is long int and the size is effectively `32-bit`.

Is it possible to have a linux system call return a `64-bit` value (of type, say, `long long int`)?

I understand that changing the size makes no sense but I am interested in learning the limitations if there are any or if this is just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On x86, the return value is put in the `eax` register, so it cannot be bigger than 32 bit; similarly, on x86-64 it is stored on `rax` (the 64-bit extension of `eax`).

In general, the trend seems to be to always use a register for the return value (which seems reasonable for system calls), so you are limited to the size of the "native integer" of the current platform. If you needed to return bigger stuff, you'd have to resort to passing the location for the output via a pointer.

Comment: Not quite... it is actually possible to return long long on a 32-bit architecture, you just have to juggle things a bit.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: with regular calls of course, but AFAIK the syscalls calling convention only allows for a register to store the return type.

Comment: It's true, but long long is handled in a special way by gcc on i386 (and other 32-bit) platforms; the results get dumped into registers  %eax and %edx or i386 type archs; the stack is not involved which is why you can have functions that have a long long return type in the first place.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: this is surely the case with regular function calls, but syscalls are a different story; have a look [here](http://articles.manugarg.com/systemcallinlinux2_6.html) and [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-4.html). As you can see, the syscalls calling convention is quite rigid (maximum six parameters in the registers and eax used for the return value) and does not have all the bells and whistles of regular function calls.

Comment: I am not talking about official calling conventions ABI  ; the OP is asking about breaking the ABI and the calling convention; there is nothing stoping the OP from breaking the calling convention (it will be incompatible) but that's just a choice. I was simply saying that gcc will spit out the assembler as I indicated without involving the stack; and put a the return values in %eax and %edx for a long long function() and a stack need-not be involved.

Comment: as an addendum in case you think long long is NOT supported as a return type for functions because there is some limitation because it's kernel space; I invite you to look at the code base in arch/i386/*/*.c ... in particular have a look at kernel/setup_32.c and look at the object code that it emits when compiled.  the long long support can easily (albiet incompatibly) be achieved in the system call gate by preserving %edx and rewriting both the kernel-space and user-space counter parts of the system call interface.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: of course it is not impossible and with enough messing around you can do whatever you want; the point is that I *am* talking about current official ABI for syscalls, and I think the question was about that. Still, you got my upvote on your answer for pointing out the changes involved to make this work.

Comment: Hmmm.... I just re-read his question. There is definitely ambiguity there, so I guess both of our answers are correct +1 to you ;)

Comment: I was looking at actually breaking the convention. Whether it is possible to modify the kernel to change the return size. So Ahmed's answer is correct but Matteo's answer is more generic about the limitations. So both of you are correct, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

I am limiting my discussion to x86_64 and i386 in this answer:

System calls are declared as `long`.

A 64-bit kernel will return a 64-bit int value back to user-space for system calls. 
A 32-bit kernel will return a 32-bit int value.

However, lets say that on the 32-bit kernel you change the return type of the system calls to long long; then they would be returned in %eax and %edx together with LSB in %eax and MSB in %edx

So your call gate (stuff in entry.S) will just have to ensure that it's not clobbering %eax and %edx on iret / ret instructions.

Your corresponding user-space wrapper functions that make the system call via int80 or via _syscall() macros on old systems or reimplementing the syscall(2) library call in the newer system to be a long long return type.